# Vb.net + AutoComplete in textboxes

Tags: vb.net, autocomplete, textbox

So I was reading a bit on AutoComplete of textboxes in VB.NET, but I can't really understand where these are stored? Is it a fully built in feature, or do I have to write some code for it to work? I've found the `AutoCompleteMode` and `AutoCompleteSource` properties of textboxes. But I want to append whatever I've written in the textbox to the autocomplete source. Do I connect the source to `My.Settings` or something? Wouldn't I have to use an array as well? Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Populating the AutoCompleteCustom Source of a textbox, adding and removing entries:
[See this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/243368/AutoComplete-Textbox)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would have to add new entries to your auto-complete data source manually... which makes sense, when you think about it: How is Windows Forms supposed to know when a new entry should be added to the list of suggestions and when the text entered is only something temporary?

You could add new values e.g. when validation of the input field happens, or when the user presses an OK / Apply button, or whatever fits your need best. But you will have to do this yourself.

The properties you've already discovered are the right ones.

```
Dim suggestions As New List(Of String)
suggestions.Add("Abba")
suggestions.Add("Nirvana")
suggestions.Add("Rolling Stones")
...
textBox.AutoCompleteSource = suggestions
```

You can bind `AutoCompleteSource` to almost anything; this is very similar to data-binding. One thing to keep in mind is that if you're adding new entries to the auto-complete data source, the UI control might not immediately notice if your data source doesn't implement the `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface.

Comment: Ok, so where is this information stored? Can I store it in My.Settings?

Comment: @Kenny. Yes. You can store it anywhere that's convenient for you.

Comment: I can't figure out the syntax. Dim suggestions As New List(Of String) = { "Abba", "Nirvana", "Rolling Stones" } doesn't fly well. I get an "End of statement expected"

Comment: Nice choice of string btw ;) I would have had Beatles, Rolling Stones and Abba though but ;)

Comment: @Kenny: You're trying to use `Array` initialisation to initialise a `List` which you can't do. You can however initialise an `Array` first and then use that to initialise the `List`, like this: `Dim suggestions As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)(New String() {"Abba", "Nirvana", "Rolling Stones"})`

Comment: @Kenny, sorry, I indeed got the syntax wrong. I always struggle a bit with VB.NET until I get things right. Corrected!

Answer (score 2):

first create the list to use as the custom source.

```
Dim MySource As New AutoCompleteStringCollection()
```

and then set the property of the textbox

```
With MyTextbox
   .AutoCompleteCustomSource = MySource
   .AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend
   .AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
End With
```

put this code in eventlistener you use for validating the input field, e.g. btnOK.Click

```
Private Sub btnOK_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnOK.Click
    MySource.Add(txtinput.text)
End Sub
```