# Display related matches from database to TextBox popup when we enter some word in textbox in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

i have some problem in Vb.net , i done Google since last 2 days but not getting any related answer of my question , qtn is when user type some text in Text Box so related that text how to display popup just like when we enter some word in Google then Google show all related fields .. guys i m attaching a snapshot please help me ..
        i m using vb.net as back end 
                and MS-Access as front end

Comment: you are talking about auto complete textbox, and vb.net is your front end and ms access is your database means back end if i am not wrong

Comment: yes frnd.. sorry but what is auto complete textbox

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152144/vb-net-autocomplete-in-textboxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey guys i got the answer 
Step by step (vb.net)
1st declare this as a  global

```
Dim lst As New List(Of String)
Dim rdrOLEDB As OleDbDataReader
Dim MySource As New AutoCompleteStringCollection()
```

2nd on form load or as per u r logic but make sure it comes only at one time means dont include this code in 3rd step( that is key down)

```
 If ComboBox1.SelectedItem <> "" Then
        ComboBox4.Enabled = True
        cmdOLEDB.CommandText = "SELECT studentname FROM StudentDetail WHERE std = '" & ComboBox1.SelectedItem & "' "
        cmdOLEDB.Connection = cnnOLEDB
        rdrOLEDB = cmdOLEDB.ExecuteReader
        If rdrOLEDB.Read = True Then
            lst.Add(rdrOLEDB.Item(0).ToString)
            While rdrOLEDB.Read
                lst.Add(rdrOLEDB.Item(0).ToString)
            End While
        End If
        rdrOLEDB.Close()
        MySource.AddRange(lst.ToArray)
        TextBox2.AutoCompleteCustomSource = MySource

        'Auto complete mode set to suggest append so that it will sugesst one
        'or more suggested completion strings it has bith ‘Suggest’ and
        '‘Append’ functionality
        TextBox2.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend

        'Set to Custom source we have filled already
        TextBox2.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource


    Else
        MsgBox("please select std.")
    End If
```

3rd step that is text box key down
       If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then   ' On enter I planned to add it the list
            If Not lst.Contains(TextBox2.Text) Then  ' If item not present already
                ' Add to the source directly
                TextBox2.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Add(TextBox2.Text)
            End If
        ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.Delete Then 'On delete key, planned to remove entry

```
        ' declare a dummy source
        Dim coll As AutoCompleteStringCollection = TextBox2.AutoCompleteCustomSource

        ' remove item from new source
        coll.Remove(TextBox2.Text)

        ' Bind the updates
        TextBox2.AutoCompleteCustomSource = coll

        ' Clear textbox
        TextBox2.Clear()

    End If                   ' End of ‘KeyCode’ condition
```

if its help full then please dont forget to click on point for other peaople search ( parden me for my bad english)